# Find element of BST with at most h + 1 comparisons

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Given a binary search tree and an element e, determine whether or not the tree contains e using at most h + 1 comparisons, where h is the height of the tree and ==, !=, >, >=, <, and <= are comparisons. Does anyone know how to approach creating this algorithm?

Comment: I'm not talking about the standard bst search algorithm--that takes at most 2h - 1 comparisons, if that's what you mean

Comment: What makes you think such an algorithm exists?

Comment: This is a question on a programming assignment using Elm, and it has been solved by others.

Comment: A single comparison cannot guarantee that you both know if a node contains your value *and* if it is not, which branch it would be in if present in the tree, unless Elm has some mechanism for doing that.  Without that, you cannot insure you don't need 2 comparisons at each interior node.

Comment: The solution almost definitely exists, and it is not unique to Elm. I don't know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write a function that finds the thing in the tree that's the smallest item that's greater than or equal to your value.

In pseudo-code:

```
function find_min_ge(x, node, min_ge) {
    if node is nil {
        return min_ge
    }
    if node.x >= x {
        return find_min_ge(x, node.left, node.x)
    } else {
        return find_min_ge(x, node.right, min_ge)
    }
}
```

Here, the "min_ge" argument is the smallest value that's >= x found so far.

Then, compare the result with x:

```
x_in_tree = find_min_ge(x, root, x + 1) == x
```

The x+1 is a dummy value that'll be returned if there's no element in the tree >= x. x+1 could be any expression that's not equal to x.

Overall, find_min_ge performs at most h ">=" comparisons, and then there's one extra "==" comparison done at the end for a total maximum of h+1 as required.